# custom admin screen on custom post tyle wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have this code for creating custom post type

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_sidebarone' );

function create_sidebarone() {
    register_post_type( 'sidebarone',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => 'Sidebar One',
                'singular_name' => 'sidebarone',
                'add_new' => 'Add New',
                'add_new_item' => 'Add Sidebar One',
                'edit' => 'Edit',
                'edit_item' => 'Edit Sidebar One',
                'new_item' => 'New Sidebar One',
                'view' => 'View',
                'view_item' => 'View Sidebar One',
                'search_items' => 'Search Sidebar One',
                'not_found' => 'No Sidebar One found',
                'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Sidebar One found in Trash',
                'parent' => 'Parent Sidebar One'
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'menu_position' => 15,
            'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'comments', 'thumbnail' ),
            'taxonomies' => array( '' ),
            'menu_icon' => get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/ggicon.png',
            'has_archive' => true
        )
    );
}
```

Now I want to achieve something to cater my needs, I want to create a custom admin screen or setting page for my custom post type, to be precise please refer to the image below:

This is the illustration of the custom post type that i've created from the code above
[image: regular custom post type]

Now, I want to customize the admin screen or the setting screen of that post type, like the image below:

[image]
Now as you can see, the admin screen or the setting screen of that post type has been customize. (the second image is an assume of what im trying to achieve, image edited)

So far, what i tried is the post type base from the first image from the codes above. Anyone, im open in any suggestion, recommendations and idea's. Very much thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this would be to create a [plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin) then you can create administrative panels by following [this guide](http://codex.wordpress.org/Adding_Administration_Menus) from wordpress.org

Note the example taken from the linked guide:

```
<?php
/** Step 2 (from text above). */
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_plugin_menu' );

/** Step 1. */
function my_plugin_menu() {
    add_options_page( 'My Plugin Options', 'My Plugin', 'manage_options', 'my-unique-identifier', 'my_plugin_options' );
}

/** Step 3. */
function my_plugin_options() {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) )  {
        wp_die( __( 'You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.'     ) );
     }
    echo '<div class="wrap">';
    echo '<p>Here is where the form would go if I actually had options.</p>';
    echo '</div>';
}
?>
```